# Vue&TypeScript: 'Could not find file' if to rewrite script section in .vue file from JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

TypeScript basically has been set in my Webpack-project, and I have **working** multiple TypeScript file. Also, in .`ts` files, `vue-property-decorator` library woks too.

When I tried to rewrite below code in **Application.vue** to TypeScript, I got error

```
Error: Could not find file: 'C:\...\development\1_Source\3_admin\3_scripts\Application.vue'.
```

**Application.vue** before (works):

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        navigationDrawerOpened: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Application.vue** after (has error):

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component} from "vue-property-decorator";

  @Component
  export default class Application extends Vue {
    private navigationDrawerOpened: boolean = false;
  }
</script>
```

**App.ts** (Application entry point)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Application from './Application.vue';
import router from './router/router';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: '#application',
  router,
  components: { Application },
  template: '<Application/>'
});
```